# How to laod files with spark inside map

Tags: scala, apache-spark

My dataset has col with paths to local files, i want to load those files using spark when i'm mapping over dataset rows

```
-----------------------
|col 1 | col ...| paths| => map(parallel) [load files into dataset -> do calculation -> save result ] 
-----------------------
```

each file is large, so i can't load them in the master, i know it's not possible to call spark context inside map.. but i'm looking for a way to run all the work in parallel

for now I convert the dataset to list and I loop over it (see code below) but I'm not happy with this method I'm looking for a better way to do it

```
ds.forEach(rowClass=> {
        rowClass.t_p.foreach(p => {
          val result = calculcation.exec(SparkConnexion.ss, rowClass.t, p)
          result.show(5, false)
          print("one done")
        })
      })
```

Comment: you can collect your df to Array[String] and put that list in `spark.read.text(list:_*)`

Comment: Yeah that's what i'm doing now but i'm looking if there are a better way for this use case

Comment: Maybe a foreachPartition could help here